# Unable to assign to data var in VueJS after Firestore storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-storage

Hi all i am encountering an issue where my data is changed back to the original assignment. For example, I have the following data below:

```
 data() {
    return {
        uid: "",
        pic: "hello",
    }
},
```

With the function below, the alert returns "hello"

```
created() {
    this.uid = fb.auth().currentUser.uid;
    this.getprofilepic();
},
```

** getprofilepic function

```
getprofilepic() {
    fb.storage().ref('users/' + this.uid + '/profile.jpg').getDownloadURL().then(imgurl => {
        this.pic = imgurl;
    })
    alert(this.pic);           // returns "hello"
},
```

If i were to put the alert into the fb.storage..., it returns the correct path as shown below:

```
getprofilepic() {
    alert("getting profile pic")
    fb.storage().ref('users/' + this.uid + '/profile.jpg').getDownloadURL().then(imgurl => {
        this.pic = imgurl;
        alert(this.pic);     // returns correct path;
    })
    
},
```

Is there a reason why the data would override again? Thank you in advance for any help! :) I would like to v-bind:src to get the path of the photo from firebase storage but "pic" returns "hello" instead. You can find my html code below:

```
<b-avatar :src = "pic" id = "profilepic" class="mr-5" size="8em"></b-avatar>
```

Comment: Every time the specific page renders again then all the assignments in the data property sets to their initial assignments.

Comment: Hi @YashMaheshwari , thanks for your comment. Do you mean that calling fb.storage().ref.... will refresh the page and also, is there any way to work around this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your question the reason is that the [`getDownloadURL()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#getdownloadurl) method is asynchronous. The result of the call to this function will be available only when the [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) returned by the method will be fulfilled. This is why we use the [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method: the handler function passed to `then()` will return the value of the URL.

What is important in the previous paragraph is the use of **will**: the method is **asynchronous** and therefore the result is not immediately returned. However, the JavaScript code continues to execute: this is why the line `alert(this.pic);` is executed with the initial `hello` value.

Try the following code:

```
getprofilepic() {
    fb.storage().ref('users/' + this.uid + '/profile.jpg').getDownloadURL().then(imgurl => {
        alert(imgurl);   // <----- See the change here
        this.pic = imgurl;
    })
    alert(this.pic);           // returns "hello"
},
```

In the console, you should first see `hello`, then the URL value.

**Conclusion:** You can only get the result of the call to the `getDownloadURL()` method in the `then()` block.

---

You will find a lot of literature on the internet and on SO on how to return the response from an asynchronous call. A good and complete example: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323). (I could have marked your question as duplicate of this question actually.)

Comment: Hi @RenaudTarnec, Thank you for the detailed explanation. I understand how it works now but well, my actual issue is that I would like to v-bind:src = "profilepic" and the data profilepic is showing "hello" instead of the actual path. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Either you start with an empty or "Loading..." value **OR** you execute this call in one of the [Vue.js lifecycle hook](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram), for example the `created` one, i such a way the component is displayed only when the correct value has been returned.

Comment: I did lace the getprofilepic() function inside created() and called the var pic using v-bind:src = "pic" as shown above (edited). the variable pic still shows the wrong data: showing "hello" instead.